# The $3 = 2$ trick on Google+

Tags: arithmetic, fake-proofs

I found out this on Google+ yesterday and I was thinking about what's the trick. Can you tell?

> How can you prove $3=2$?
>
> This seems to be an anomaly or whatever you call in mathematics. Or maybe I'm just plain dense.
>
> See this illustration:
>
> $$ -6 = -6 $$
>
> $$ 9-15 = 4-10 $$
>
> Adding $\frac{25}{4}$ to both sides:
>
> $$ 9-15+ \frac{25}{4} = 4-10+ \frac{25}{4} $$
>
> Changing the order
>
> $$ 9+\frac{25}{4}-15 = 4+\frac{25}{4}-10 $$
>
> This is just like $a^2 + b^2 - 2a b = (a-b)^2$. Here $a_1 = 3, b_1=\frac{5}{2}$ for  L.H.S, and $a_2 =2, b_2=\frac{5}{2}$ for R.H.S. So it can be expressed as follows:
>
> $$ \left(3-\frac{5}{2} \right) \left(3-\frac{5}{2} \right) = 
> \left(2-\frac{5}{2} \right) \left( 2-\frac{5}{2} \right) $$
>
> Taking positive square root on both sides:
>
> $$ 3 - \frac{5}{2} = 2 - \frac{5}{2} $$
>
> $$  3 = 2 .$$

I think it's something near the root.

Comment: 4=4 => (2) x (2) = (-2) x (-2) => ("taking positive roots on both sides") => 2 = -2

Comment: Why the -1 point?

Comment: When you take square roots of both sides, you should write "$\pm$" in front of one of them.  Then no paradox arises.

Comment: +1.  This adds another example to our collections of fallacious proofs with which to challenge students to identify the error.  (Although it's not really all that different from some standard ones.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

$2-(5/2)$ is **not** a positive square root.

Comment: But [2- (5/2)][2- (5/2)] is positive.

Comment: @CHarlie: Yes, $(-0.5)\times(-0.5)$ is indeed positive, but $-0.5$ (one of the square *roots*) is not positive.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess.

Answer (score 15):

**HINT** $\ $ You erroneously inferred $\rm\ x^2 =\: (-x)^2\ \Rightarrow\ x\: =\: -x\:,\ $ for $\rm\ x\:=\:1/2\:.$

Answer (score 15):

Back when I was in academia, I taught the "how to prove stuff" course, and one of the first problems that I'd give (which, I admit, I borrowed from my graduate adviser) was along the same vein, namely:  criticize the "proof" of the following "theorem" or rethink your life!

**"Theorem"**:  You have all the money you need.

**"Proof:"**  Let $M$ denote the amount of money you have and $N$ denote the amount of money you need.  Let $A=\frac{M+N}{2}$ be the average of $M$ and $N$.  Then, we have:

$2A=M+N$

$2A(M-N)=(M+N)(M-N)=M^2 - N^2$

$M^2-2AM = N^2-2AN$

$M^2-2AM + A^2 = N^2-2AN + A^2$

$(M-A)^2 = (N-A)^2$

And taking the square root of both sides, we have $M-A=N-A$, and hence $M=N$.  $\blacksquare$

Comment: Also, **please** don't show this answer to politicians!

Answer (score 3):

On the right side, when you say to take the positive square root of $(2-5/2)(2-5/2)$, you're taking a $-.5 [(2-5/2)]$ instead of $.5$

It's easy to see if you multiply out all the numbers in each step.

Comment: This one is too easy. You cannot divide for (a-b) since a = b.

Comment: (I deleted it since it's not part of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not true in the reals that if $ x^2=y^2 $ then x=y.  For example, if $ (-2)^2=2^2 $, but 2 does not equal -2.  The scheme of inference used in the last step in general isn't valid.