# How to explain this $3=2$ proof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The $3 = 2$ trick on Google+](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68913/the-3-2-trick-on-google)

I saw google some links

http://www.astahost.com/info/tiiiss-ramanujams-proof-flaws.html

$$-6 = -6 $$

$$9-15 = 4-10 $$

adding $\frac{25}{4}$ to both sides:

$$9-15+ \Big(\frac{25}{4} \Big) = 4-10+ \Big(\frac{25}{4} \Big) $$

(This is just like : $a^2 – 2ab + b^2 = (a-b)^2$.)

Here $a = 3$, $b=\frac{5}{2}$ for L.H.S., and $a =2$, $b=\frac{5}{2}$ for R.H.S.

So it can be expressed as follows:

$$ \Big(3-\frac{5}{2} \Big)^2 = \Big(2-\frac{5}{2}\Big)^2 $$

Taking positive square root on both sides:

$$ 3 - \frac{5}{2} = 2 - \frac{5}{2} $$

$$ 3 = 2 $$

but not clear. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** $\displaystyle {\sqrt[n]{a^n} = |a|}$, if $n$ is even and square root is $n=2$.

So, $$2− \frac52=-\frac{1}{2}$$ is not a positive square root making your assumption, and hence, the entire proof, flawed.

Comment: but how to proof Ramanujam's?

Comment: @anglimass:I don't understand. Please rephrase your question.